# eve U.R.R.A. doesn't work with HMAC

Tags: python-3.x, eve

run.py:

```
class HMACAuth(HMACAuth):
    def check_auth(self, userid, hmac_hash, headers, data, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        accounts = app.data.driver.db['accounts']
        user = accounts.find_one({'username': userid})
        if user and '_id' in user:
            secret_key = user['secret_key']
            self.set_request_auth_value(user['_id'])

        # in this implementation we only hash request data, ignoring the headers.
        hm = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf-8'), data, sha1).digest()

        return user and base64.b64encode(hm).decode() == hmac_hash
```

settings.py:

```
vms = {
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'name',
    },
    'cache_control': '',
    'cache_expires': 0,
    'public_methods': [],
    'public_item_methods': [],
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
    'item_methods': ['GET','PATCH','DELETE'],
    'auth_field': 'user_id',
    'schema': vm_schema,
}
```

my problem is that every user is receiving all the VMs info when he/she send a GET request to `localhost:5000/vms`.
With the `TokenAuth` authentication this didn't happen.
What am I missing??

PS: Eve 0.5-dev on Python 3.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Since everything was working fine with token based authentication, and since there's nothing really different between the two methods expect the custom  class itself, I would investigate around its behavior.

I would start by checking if documents are actually being stored with the proper `user_id` value, maybe by using the mongo shell. If not, make sure that the documents that you are inspecting have been saved with your custom HMAC class active. Add a breakpoint and track your code, simple stuff like that. Hope this helps

Comment: this is strange! The `_id` of the created user is `544ff79fe555c028869380f7` while the `_id` of the created vms are `544ff79fe555c028869380f8` and `544ff79fe555c028869380f9`. How can this be possible? :O
If i write `print(user['_id'])` it is all ok but it is stored a different values :/

Comment: The problem is that the field `user_id` isn't created with the HMACAuth class. I cannot figure out why I get this strange behaviour...

Comment: I checked with `self.get_request_auth_value()` and the value is correct :( So why it isn't stored inside the db? -.-